Issues with dataframe shapes in creating a seismogram using Python
I have been trying to create a seismogram for quite a while but keep running into bugs. I was successful in creating a seismogram for a set of small data, but am now working with a larger set and seem to be running into issues with keeping time consistent with data (dropping NaNs while moving through data) and ignoring shapes of dataframes... the goal is to have this code be usable for different sizes of dataframes.
This is the code script for what I successfully generated a seismogram with: (excluding my csv name)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#converting time data to integer values
rawTime= pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[4:4601, 0], format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
deltaTime = (rawTime-rawTime.iloc[0]).astype(np.int64) /(10e8*60)
#name generation for instruments
names = ["GeoFlex" + str(i) for i in range(1,31,1)]

#pulling indexed data
tiltX = data.iloc[4:4601, range(5, 122, 4)].set_axis([names], axis="columns")
tiltY = data.iloc[4:4601, range(6, 123, 4)].set_axis([names], axis="columns")
voltage = data.iloc[4:4601, range(7, 124, 4)].set_axis([names], axis="columns")
tempC = data.iloc[4:4601, range(8, 125, 4)].set_axis([names], axis="columns")

#removing NaN values without changing index
tiltXWithoutNaN = tiltX.join(deltaTime).dropna().astype(float)
tiltYWithoutNaN = tiltY.join(deltaTime).dropna().astype(float)
tempCWithoutNaN = tempC.join(deltaTime).dropna().astype(float)
voltageWithoutNaN = voltage.join(deltaTime).dropna().astype(float)

#calculations for displacement (equations provided by GeoFlex documentation)
displacementMagnitudeX =              (tiltXWithoutNaN.iloc[:,0:30]*0.6).diff(axis=0).dropna().join(deltaTime).rename(columns={"Column1":"Time"})
displacementMagnitudeY = (tiltYWithoutNaN.iloc[:,0:30]*0.6).diff(axis=0).dropna().join(deltaTime).rename(columns={"Column1":"Time"})

#some good ol pythagorean
displacementTotal = pd.DataFrame(np.sqrt((
    abs(displacementMagnitudeX.iloc[:,0:30])**2)+(
    abs(displacementMagnitudeY.iloc[:,0:30])**2))).join(deltaTime).rename(columns={"Column1":"Time"})

#plotting
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 7})
fig = plt.figure(layout='constrained')
spec = fig.add_gridspec(2,2)

#plot1
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,:])
ax3.plot(displacementTotal.iloc[:,30],displacementTotal.iloc[:,0:10], ls=':', linewidth='0.7')
ax3.axis([0,9000,0,0.3])
ax3.set_xlabel("Time[minutes]")
ax3.set_ylabel("Magnitude of Displacement of Sensor [mm]")
ax3.set_title("Fig 1: Seismogram")

Now here is the code I have been attempting to use for a newer, larger data set:
# importing packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt


# name generation for instruments
names = ["GeoFlex" + str(i) for i in range(1,51,1)]

# dropping NaN and loading displacemts 
data2 = data.dropna(inplace=True)
tiltX = data2.iloc[:, 5]
tiltY = data2.iloc[:, 6]

# time to datetime
time = pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[4:, 0], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
data2.set_index(time, inplace=True)

#Editing time to fit format
minutes_since_start = (displacementTotal.index - displacementTotal.index[0]).total_seconds() / 60

# Convert tiltX, tiltY, etc., to DataFrame, join with time, then drop NaN values
tiltX_df = tiltX.to_frame(name='tiltX')
tiltY_df = tiltY.to_frame(name='tiltY')

# Join each with time. Here we assume 'time' is the DataFrame with 'Time' as its index.
tiltXWithoutNaN = tiltX_df.join(time, how='inner').dropna()
tiltYWithoutNaN = tiltY_df.join(time, how='inner').dropna()

# Now, you can apply 'astype(float)' to just the sensor data columns, if necessary:
tiltXWithoutNaN['tiltX'] = tiltXWithoutNaN['tiltX'].astype(float)
tiltYWithoutNaN['tiltY'] = tiltYWithoutNaN['tiltY'].astype(float)

#calculations for displacement (equations provided by GeoFlex documentation)
displacementMagnitudeX = (tiltXWithoutNaN.iloc[:,0:50]*0.6).diff(axis=0).dropna().join(time).rename(columns={"Column1":"Time"})
displacementMagnitudeY = (tiltYWithoutNaN.iloc[:,0:50]*0.6).diff(axis=0).dropna().join(time).rename(columns={"Column1":"Time"})

#pythagorean
displacementTotal = pd.DataFrame(np.sqrt((
        abs(displacementMagnitudeX.iloc[:,0:50])**2)+(
        abs(displacementMagnitudeY.iloc[:,0:50])**2))).join(time).rename(columns={"Column1":"Time"})

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(minutes_since_start, y, label='Sensor Displacement')
plt.xlabel("Time [minutes]")
plt.ylabel("Magnitude of Displacement of Sensor [mm]")
plt.title("Fig 1: Seismogram")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Any ideas why my plots are either empty or just filled with errors?

data2 = data.dropna(inplace=True) inplace=True is removing NA inplace and return None. use data2 = data.dropna() instead
